# wp8.1 can not find the class "IPAddress"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to use the class "IPAddress" in System.Net on wp8.1. I also write the code "using System.Net;". But it still can not find this class. The code is as follows:

```
  using System.Net;
  ................

  IPAddress ip = new IPAddress("192.168.1.2");
```

Visual Studio 2013 tell me that "Generate class for 'IPAddress'".

Looking forward for anyone's reply!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454046.aspx), there is no such class available in the `System.Net` namespace WP 8.1. This is due to the fact that WP 8.1 now runs on the WinRT runtime, which has a slightly different API than the previous WP API.

In the WinRT API, there is a class called [`HostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.hostname.aspx) in the `Windows.Network` namespace. This class represents a hostname *or* an IP address, so you should probably be using that class. You should change your code to use the following code:

```
HostName ip = new HostName("192.168.1.2");
```

Comment: Is there any solution that can convert HostName to IPAddress? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think not, as they live in different .NET framework subsets. Either you work with `IPAddress` or you work with `HostName`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which subset of the .NET framework you're targetting.

IPAddress exists in the full fat version of the framework but is not supported by the portable class library version of it.

I believe that WP 8.1 apps target the PCL .NET Framework, rather than the full fat version.

Look through the list of objects here and hover over the icons to see what is supported and in which version

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I see this link. IPAddress doesn't hover over the portable class icon. But when I click in, it's version information says that it is supported in Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: @wdsoft try viewing the references assemblies in the object browser to see which versions you are referencing. Also look in the project properties as this might indicate which version of the framework you are targetting.

Comment: It says the assembly is in System.dll, but when I add in the reference, visual stdio 2013 pop up a warning window which says "This component is already automatically referenced by the build system". My .NET version is 4.5.

Comment: @wdsoft what type of project are you building? (i.e. class library, portable class library etc)

Comment: An app of windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

.NET is open source since November 2014, so you can simply copy the classes from here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs

Comment: Didn't get the down vote, I have this problem and I'm using this solution.